# Javascript bitwise logic in a for loop

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I have been trying to improve my Javascript and have been going through Coderbyte's challenges. The only easy challenge left which I cant seem to crack perfectly is called "Array Addition 1"*. I am trying to compare my code with another user who has got a perfect response with the following:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) { 

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
  }

  var max = arr[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    max = Math.max(max, arr[i]);
  }
  //everything above makes sense
  for (var i = 0, l = 1 << arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var s = 0, cnt = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (i & (1 << j)) {
        s += arr[j];
        cnt++;
      }
    }

    if (cnt > 1 && s == max) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;       
}

ArrayAdditionI(/* some array*/)
```

Could someone please help with a plain English explanation of how the bitwise operators are being used above?

[*]

> Have the function ArrayAdditionI(arr) take the array of numbers stored
>   in arr and return the string true if any combination of numbers in the
>   array can be added up to equal the largest number in the array,
>   otherwise return the string false. For example: if arr contains [4, 6,
>   23, 10, 1, 3] the output should return true because 4 + 6 + 10 + 3 =
>   23. The array will not be empty, will not contain all the same elements, and may contain negative numbers.

Comment: The author of that code uses it to get all permutations of elements

Comment: Thanks, so I am assuming (but not sure) l represents all logical combinations of the elements in the array. What I am not understanding is how it is being used as a boolean condition in the if statement. How, for example would 0 & 64 = true or false?

Comment: when you check for the bit set - you check if the number is not falsy. So if it's `0` - it's treated as `false`, `true` otherwise. Check `10 & (1 << 0)` and `10 & (1 << 1)`

Comment: ps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that code author creates all permutations of elements.

Explanation:

Assuming we have 4 elements:

1. Outer loop iterates over `0..15`
2. Inner loop checks if a particular bit of `i` is set `i & (1 << j)`
3. If it's set - accumulating the sum
4. After we iterated over all bits - check if sum equals to expected

PS: `cnt > 1` required to check that sum creates of multiple numbers not one

PPS: detailed explanation of one iteration.

Let's imagine the current `i = 10` (`1010` binary).

So when we perform a nested loop - we'll check that only 2nd and 4th bits are set, it means that we will try to sum 2nd and 4th elements of array. And then check is their sum equals to the maximum value.